# How to Create 2D Grid by Repeating a Component certain times in a Loop in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am Working on Movie Ticket Booking Website. I Want to make a Grid Layout of 4x7. So What i Thought is i would Create a button Component and repeat it in Loop Several Times.

Pseudo Code:

```
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<7;j++){
        button Component();
    }
    newline Component();
}
```

But this type of thing is not supported in reactjs. So What Can i Do for Implementation of above thing? Also When a button is clicked i want to change its color for that i have given ID to button Component so i can do it by DOM Manipulation but how to do that using UseState?

EDIT: I am done with array part but what about Color Change now? I Tried DOM but it returns NULL

CODE:

```
const items=[];
    for(let i=1;i<=20;i++){
        let style={
            backgroundColor:"White"
        };
        items.push(<button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>changeColor(i)} style={style} id={"button"+i}/>);
    }
    function changeColor(index) {
        document.getElementById("index").style.backgroundColor="Green";
    }
This Thing returns NULL i Do not know why
```

Comment: What to do you mean this isn't supported? You can `map()` directly in JSX, as well as pass pre-composed arrays of components. see: [React: Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Yeah i Figured that Part out but what about color changing when a certain button is clicked i am still stuck there.

Comment: Well that's a different question. Add the code that you have regarding color changing to the question, and what isn't working about it. Your `onClick` is already passing the event, which will contain a referenct to the button that triggered it...

Comment: hi i edited see that Please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using direct DOM manipulation is not recommended, you should instead leverage the reactive render cycle that React provides.

Here is a snippet which declares a `Button` component that handles its own internal state as an example. Mutiple `Button`s are rendered inside a `map()` in the parent, and each button then controls its own `active` state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    {[1,2,3].map(n =>(
      <Button key={n} label={'Button' + n} />
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}

function Button({label}) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setActive(a => !a);
  };
  
  return (
    <button 
      type='button' 
      className={active ? 'active' : ''} 
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
    {label}
    </button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

But generally buttons will be used to interact directly with the parent's state, in which case the click handler and state logic will be declared in the parent, with relevant properties being passed down to the children.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    {id: 1, label: 'Button 1', active: false}, 
    {id: 2, label: 'Button 2', active: false}, 
    {id: 3, label: 'Button 3', active: false}]);

  const handleClick = (buttonId) => {
    setButtons(buttons => buttons.map(b => 
      b.id === buttonId
        ? {...b, active: !b.active}
        : b));
  };

  return (
    <div>
    {buttons.map(b =>(
      <Button key={b.id} id={b.id} label={b.label} onClick={handleClick} active={b.active}  />
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}

function Button({label, id, onClick, active}) {
  
  return (
    <button 
      type='button' 
      onClick={() => onClick(id)}
      className={active ? 'active' : ''}
    >
    {label}
    </button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I Got to Learn New Concept of using states Today.